# Insert a loading text message before a div gets populated?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am tweaking my function below and had an issue. I'd like a loading text message to be inserted right before `#project-container` fills up with HTML and disappear once `response` has been inserted.

However, if I insert:

`$('#project-container').html("my text here");`

...right before:

`$('#project-container').html(response);`

Then, `response` doesn't show since the div is already populated with "my text here". Is there another method I can use?

```
    function projectShow() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            url: ajaxURL,
            data: {'action': 'load-content', post_id: post_id },
            success: function(response) {
                $('#project-wrapper').addClass('activated');
                $('#project-container').html(response);         <---I want it inserted
                $('.post-container').addClass('fadeInUp');          before this line.
                $('.close-button').addClass('fadeOutDown');
                $('#project-wrapper .entry-title').shuffleLetters();
            return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: please make an alert on response and tell me what it is alerting in response,

Comment: have you tried making $('#project-container').empty(); method call before running $('#project-container').html(response); ?

Comment: Your question does not make sense. If you do .html("My text here") and then .html(response), the "My text here" is overwritten. Perhaps you mean to do html("My text here") and then .append(response) or to do .html("Please wait") before the actual ajax call

Comment: better to do console.log() on response because you can't alert objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a 'Loading' message, show it upon `beforeSend` event, and hide it on `success`:

```
function projectShow() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        url: ajaxURL,
        data: {'action': 'load-content', post_id: post_id },
        beforeSend: function() { $('#project-container').html("Loading, Please wait"); },
        success: function(response) {
            $('#project-wrapper').addClass('activated');
            $('#project-container').html(response);
            $('.post-container').addClass('fadeInUp');
            $('.close-button').addClass('fadeOutDown');
            $('#project-wrapper .entry-title').shuffleLetters();
        return false;
        }
    });
}
```

See [Ajax Events](http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/)

Comment: This is a great solution. The only issue is that when `#project-wrapper` gets the `activated` class added by a click event, it CSS transitions from `max-height:0` to `max-height:500`. Therefore, when I first click on the link that activates `#project-wrapper`, the loading message doesn't show because `max-height` is still set to `0` at that point. Sorry if that's a bit unclear.

Comment: @J82, Either add the `activated` class on `beforeSend` as well, or set `max-height` appropriately.

Comment: Of course! Thank you, can't believe I didn't think of that. I guess that happens when you've been working for 48 hours straight lol.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably add the loading message just before the AJAX call. It makes no sense to do it in the success callback, since the two operations will happen in the same cycle and chances are you'll always see just one. This should do it:

```
function projectShow() {
    // add the initial text here
    $('#project-container').html("my text here"); 
    // add the initial class here for height issues from the comments
    // $('#project-wrapper').addClass('activated');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        url: ajaxURL,
        data: {'action': 'load-content', post_id: post_id },
        success: function(response) {
            $('#project-wrapper').addClass('activated');
            $('#project-container').html(response);         <---I want it inserted
            $('.post-container').addClass('fadeInUp');          before this line.
            $('.close-button').addClass('fadeOutDown');
            $('#project-wrapper .entry-title').shuffleLetters();
        return false;
        }
    });
}
```

As said in the comments, if you wish to keep the original text then append the response to it (either by using append(), or concatting them, or whatever method you like best).

See the both ways in action below:

```js
function projectShow(keep) {
  $('#project-container').html("my text here");
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    url: 'http://hayageektest.appspot.com/cross-domain-cors/post.php',
    //data: {'action': 'load-content', post_id: post_id },
    success: function(response) {
      //$('#project-wrapper').addClass('activated');
      if (keep)
        $('#project-container').append(response); 
      else
        $('#project-container').html(response); 
      //$('.post-container').addClass('fadeInUp');     //     before this line.
      //$('.close-button').addClass('fadeOutDown');
      //$('#project-wrapper .entry-title').shuffleLetters();
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="projectShow()">Click me</button>
<button onclick="projectShow(true)">This one will keep the original! Click it. <br /></button>

<div id="project-container"></div>
```

Comment: This is a great solution as well. I'm going to repeat what I said to the other guy. The only issue is that when `#project-wrapper` gets the `activated` class added by a click event, it CSS transitions from `max-height:0` to `max-height:500`. Therefore, when I first click on the link that activates `#project-wrapper`, the loading message doesn't show because `max-height` is still set to `0` at that point.

Comment: Right, I had no idea about that since it's not in the question. But you can add the activated class when you do the first html change. There, added that to my answer.